# Change text of PAGE N OF M of mvcgrid.net

Tags: mvcgrid.net

I am using mvcgrid.net for showing my information in tables in a mvc project 
How ever it is working properly I want to change

```
 Showing 1 to 10 of 27 entries
```

of footer and

```
 next and previous
```

texts of grid but I didn't find an API for that , Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am configuring my Grid as:

```
    GridDefaults gridDefaults = new GridDefaults()
    {
        RenderingMode = RenderingMode.Controller,
        ViewPath = "~/Views/MVCGrid/_Grid.cshtml",
        NoResultsMessage = "Sorry, no results were found",
        ItemsPerPage = 25,
        MaxItemsPerPage = 200
    };
```

and I update the text of anything I need in the _Grid.cshtml file or any custom View I use instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Custom Style**

To use a custom style for your table, you can implement the `IMVCGridRenderingEngine` to create your table. Everything you need to populate your table will be given to you in the `RenderingModel` object. Once you have the implementation, set the property on your grid definition to use your new rendering engine:

```
gridDef.DefaultRenderingEngine = typeof(CustomHtmlRenderingEngine);
```

This same method could also be used to create custom export formats.
You can find it from the link.
http://mvcgrid.net/demo/customstyle